# Trying to validate user input for repeating values in 2D array

Tags: c++, validation, multidimensional-array, repeat

So I'm working on a Lo Shu Magic Square for my first programming class and I'm stuck. I'm sure everyone here will know what that is but just in case, it's a 2D array that takes 9 numbers from user input, but they have to be between that range (1-9) and also non repeating (where I'm stuck).

I can validate for numbers within the 1-9 range, but I'm having trouble also validating for the second condition of non-repeating numbers

Here's my code for the function that takes user input:

(Oh yea, the 2D array is 3x3 so ROWS = 3 and COLS = 3 and they're being passed to this function)

```
// Get numbers
void getNumbers(int magicSquare[][COLS], int ROWS)
{
    cout << "\nEnter Nine Numbers (1-9)" << endl;
    int num;
    int n = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
        {
            cout << "\tNumber " << (n + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> num;
            magicSquare[r][c] = num;
            n++;

            // Input validation
            // Validate against numbers outside the range
            while (num < 1 || num > 9)
            {
                cout << "\tError ... Invalid number. Try again" << endl 
                << endl;
                cout << "\tNumber " << (n) << ": ";
                cin >> num;
                magicSquare[r][c] = num;
            }

            // Validate against repeating numbers
            while (...)                         //OMEGA STUCK
            {
                cout << "\tError ... " << num << " is already in the 
                Lo Shu Square. Try again" << endl <<endl;
                cout << "\tNumber " << (n) << ": ";
                cin >> num;
                magicSquare[r][c] = num;
            }
            
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I have tried several approaches, from using while loops, to trying temp arrays, and I'm currently attempting to create a new bool function and pass the array and input to it but with little success.

```
// Validate against repeating numbers
while (repeatNumbers(magicSquare, num))  // Calling boolean function (defined below)
{
    cout << "\tError ... " << num << " is already in the Lo Shu Square. 
    Try again" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\tNumber " << (n) << ": ";
    cin >> num;
    magicSquare[r][c] = num;    
}

...

// Validate against repeating numbers function
bool repeatNumbers(int magicSquare[][COLS], int num)
{
    bool status;

    if (num == magicSquare[COLS][COLS])  //Here I get an error: 
    {                                    //"Reading invalid data from                                          
        status = true;                   //'magicSquare[COLS]'.
    }
    else
    {
        status = false;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that reading a partially filled-in array is well-behaved, what's the best approach? I can't arrive at the correct way, and I just KNOW I'm missing something that is quite logical which my tired brain can't think of at this point.

Any ideas on how to test for both conditions?

Comment: When you say "repeating", do you mean actual repeating as in `1 2 2 3` where the value `2` is repeating, or multiple values like `1 2 1 3` where you have multiple values `1`?

Comment: And if `magicSquare` is a matrix with `COLS x COLS` values, then `magicSquare[COLS][COLS]` will be out of bounds.

Comment: And on a different note, if you have some code like `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }`, then you can replace it by `return condition;`.

Comment: Only numbers from 1-9 can be entered, and each number can only be entered once, meaning they cannot repeat.

Comment: So then you want unique values, like `1 2 1 3` is not allowed because there are multiple values `1`. Then I recommend you use a [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), and read input until the size of the set it what you want (i.e. `while (myset.size() != ROWS * COLS) { /* Read input into myset */ }`) That will guarantee unique values.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not familiar with using  'std::unordered_set' as it hasn't been covered in class yet. Most we've seen is up to arrays, vectors, loops, if/else, etc. I know that would work since you're suggesting it, but I think we have to use only what we have covered so far :/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude also just so I can learn this well, when you say I can replace `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` with `return condition`,  do you mean that I can just write `if (condition) { return condition;} else {return condition;}` like so?

Comment: Take for example `if (num == magicSquare[COLS][COLS])` condition (skipping the out-of-bounds issue), then you can just do `return num == magicSquare[COLS][COLS];`. There's no need for the `if` statement.